# Which chemical and hormonal effects on heart are by metabolites?

Tags: physiology, endocrinology, cardiology, blood-circulation

I am thinking which hormonal and chemical effects from:

- catecholamines
- thyroxin
- corticosteroids
- sex hormones
- prostaglandins
- Ca2+
- Na+
- K+

can be be regarded as metabolites i.e. intermediates or products of metabolism.

I got this question

> Account for chemical and hormonal effects on the heart.

and I am thinking if I should include metabolites as a factor as

> Metabolites by intrinsic autoregulative system locally

because the autoregulation of heart is very important factor in the physiology of the heart.

**Can you regard some metabolites as having hormonal and chemical effects?**

Comment: Strictly speaking, hormones are either steroid derivatives or peptides, which transduce their effect in specific ways (e.g., diffusion into the cell to bind a target in the case of steroids,  or signalling through a surface receptor for peptides). Catecholamines are neurotransmitters and not considered hormones by the classical definition. The effects can either be autocrine, paracrine or endocrine depending on the distance of action. Ions will typically affect the electrical conductivity of the myocardium and can be considered passive in nature, but ions are not metabolites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ions are not hormones. Ions are not metabolites either.

Technically, anything that is not directly absorbed from environment but is synthesized/modified in the body is a metabolite. 
Even if you don't consider polypeptides as metabolites (which for some reason are not classified as metabolites in scientific parlance), all the molecules that you mention are metabolites with known biosynthetic pathways.

Comment: You are right about ions. I missed the word "chemical" in the whole discussion.